# What is wrong with my SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am getting an "Incorrect syntax near '+' error at the following line:

```
Select * FROM  + @DATABASE_NAME + '.' + @SCHEMA_NAME + '.' + @TABLE_NAME;
```

Here is my SQL:

```
Declare @TABLE_NAME varchar(10)
Declare @SCHEMA_NAME varchar(10)
Declare @DATABASE_NAME varchar(10)

Set @TABLE_NAME = 'Freshmen';
Set @SCHEMA_NAME = 'stu';
Set @DATABASE_NAME = 'Student';

Select * FROM  + @DATABASE_NAME + '.' + @SCHEMA_NAME + '.' + @TABLE_NAME;
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: jeez 5 downvotes kind of seems like piling on, not like s/he's responsible for those 17m questions. But Mr/Ms 793468 you have one other question involving dynamic sql you should accept the answer on or follow up on anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use variables for the database or tables on your `FROM`. The only way would be to use dynamic sql (but before take a look at [this link](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)).

```
Declare @TABLE_NAME varchar(10)
Declare @SCHEMA_NAME varchar(10)
Declare @DATABASE_NAME varchar(10)
Declare @QUERY VARCHAR(4000)

Set @TABLE_NAME = 'Freshmen';
Set @SCHEMA_NAME = 'stu';
Set @DATABASE_NAME = 'Student';
Set @QUERY = 'Select * FROM ' +  QUOTENAME(@DATABASE_NAME) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@SCHEMA_NAME) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TABLE_NAME)

EXEC(@QUERY)
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing an `e` on the third `declare`

and basically, you cant run this, you would need to load your select on a string and exec the string:

```
Declare @TABLE_NAME varchar(10)
Declare @SCHEMA_NAME varchar(10)
Declare @DATABASE_NAME varchar(10)

Set @TABLE_NAME = 'Freshmen';
Set @SCHEMA_NAME = 'stu';
Set @DATABASE_NAME = 'Student';

declare @mySQL varchar(50)
set @mySql= 'Select * FROM ' +  @DATABASE_NAME + '.' + @SCHEMA_NAME + '.' + @TABLE_NAME
exec(@mySql)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do this using the [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) function

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @sql varchar(max)

Declare @TABLE_NAME varchar(10)
Declare @SCHEMA_NAME varchar(10)
Declare @DATABASE_NAME varchar(10)

set @sql = 'select * from [' + @database_name + '].[' + @schema_name + '].[' + @table_name + ']'

exec (@sql)
```